# Using temporary tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a temporary table.Then used join statements to insert data into the table.Then I retrieved values to list from the table. Does this temporary table have better performance and is it a good idea to use this method?

```
    $tmp_table = mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (id int NOT NULL,name varchar(255),address varchar(255))");
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp_table(id,name,address) SELECT a.id,a.name,b.address FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id");
    $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)){
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['address'];
    }
```

Comment: why not use a view?  or just a query?

Comment: If we use temporary table they will be deleted when current client session terminates

Comment: That query doesn't really seem to be in need of a temp table.

Comment: what about concurrent users?

Comment: Ok thanks then in which situation can we use temporary table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!! Not at all rather using raw queries works better and less overhead.

> Use Temp table, if you're fetching several resultsets that contain a lot of common
>   data, it can make sense to obtain a single resultset that has all the
>   data that's required, store it in a temporary table, and then select
>   from this temporary table as needed. Similarly, when repeatedly
>   referring to the same subset of table data, it's often faster and more
>   economical to store results in a temporary table, rather than
>   repeating a complex join several times.